# Active Link not working in router link when the data passed through the router is daynamic

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-cli-3

If clicked on this link,

`<b-nav-item to="/registro/0" class="registro-link mr-4">`

the li tag shows shows it's active css property but when the link becomes
`/registro/123` or any other number except `/0`, it disables its active class.

Can someone help?

Comment: Show your route, please.

Comment: {
      path: "/registro/:totalapagar",
      name: "registro",
      component: () =>
        import("./views/Registro.vue")
},

Comment: You should add code that we'll be able to run and reproduce this error.